# почему этот код не выполняется, а вместо этого выводится то, что указано под кодом, и как это исправить?

Tags: python, turtle

```
from turtle import *
left(90)
penup()
forward(3000)
right(90)
forward(3000)
pendown()
for x in range(10):
    forward(750)
    right(90)
penup()
done()
v = 0
for x in range(26):
    for y in range(26):
        goto(x * 30, y * 30)
        dot(5)
for x in range(25):
    for y in range(25):
        if -x / 3 ** 0.5 + 25 > y > x / 3 ** 0.5:
            v += 1
print(v)
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/79063/pythonArcade/курсы ЕГЭ/9,01.py", line 20, in <module>
    forward(3000)
  File "<string>", line 8, in forward
  File "C:\Users\79063\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\turtle.py", line 1637, in forward
    self._go(distance)
  File "C:\Users\79063\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\turtle.py", line 1605, in _go
    self._goto(ende)
  File "C:\Users\79063\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\turtle.py", line 3179, in _goto
    self._update()
  File "C:\Users\79063\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\turtle.py", line 2660, in _update
    self._update_data()
  File "C:\Users\79063\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\turtle.py", line 2646, in _update_data
    self.screen._incrementudc()
  File "C:\Users\79063\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\turtle.py", line 1292, in _incrementudc
    raise Terminator
turtle.Terminator
```

Comment: У меня код работает без ошибок. А то, что в тексте ошибки упоминается какая-то загадочная строка 20, намекает на то, что вы что-то не договариваете

Comment: Полностью согласен с @andreymal. Работает, только очень странно. Улетает в никуда, рисует там квадратную рамку, возвращается, рисует квадрат из точек... Что-то вычисляет... Ах да, на методе `done()` зависала. Пришлось закомментить. Если хотите, чтобы помогли, то выложите полную прогу.

Comment: Это и есть полная прога. Просто до этого были проги к другим задачам.  Скорее всего, на этой строке произошёл сбой программы.